# Proof of convolution theorem for Laplace transform

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, convolution, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The convolution theorem for Laplace transform states that
$$\mathcal{L}\{f*g\}=\mathcal{L}\{f\}\cdot\mathcal{L}\{g\}.$$
The standard proof uses Fubini-like argument of switching the order of integration:
$$\int_0^\infty d\tau \int_{\tau}^\infty  e^{-st}f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\,dt=\int_0^\infty dt\int_0^te^{-st}f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\,d\tau$$
Fubini's theorem says that one can switch the order of *integration*. But what we have in the iterated integrals are not integrals, but *limits* of integrals (i.e., improper integrals). Are we justified to treat them like "proper" integrals and switch their order?

Comment: Fubini is generally proven using Lebesgue integration which just needs the double integral to be absolutely convergent, with no limiting process at infinity being involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align*}\mathcal{L}\{f\}({s})\cdot\mathcal{L}\{g\}({s})&=\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-{s}t}{f}(t)\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-{s}u}{g}(u)\,du\right)\\
&=\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\left(\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}t}{f}(t)\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}u}{g}(u)\,du\right)
\end{align*}
By Fubini's theorem,
\begin{align*}\left(\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}t}{f}(t)\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}u}{g}(u)\,du\right)&=\int_0^{{L}}\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du\\
&=\iint_{R_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du,
\end{align*}
where $R_{{L}}$ is the square region $$0\leq t\leq {{L}},\qquad 0\leq u\leq {{L}}.$$
Let $T_{{L}}$ be the triangular region
$$0\leq t\leq {{L}},\qquad 0\leq u\leq {{L}},\qquad t+u\leq {{L}}.$$
Provided that ${f}$ and ${g}$ are bounded by exponential functions,
$$\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\iint_{R_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du=\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\iint_{T_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du.$$
Now, the function
$$\varphi(v,u)=(v-u,u)$$
maps $D_{{L}}$ bijectively onto $T_{{L}}$, where $D_{{L}}$ is the triangular region
$$0\leq v\leq {{L}},\qquad 0\leq u\leq {{L}},\qquad v\geq u.$$
[image]
The component functions of $\varphi$ are
$$t(v,u)=v-u\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad u(v,u)=u,$$
so the Jacobian of $\varphi$ is
$$J\varphi=\det\begin{bmatrix}t_v&t_u\\u_v&u_u\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=1.$$
Hence,
$$\iint_{T_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du=\iint_{D_{{L}}}e^{-{s}v}{f}(v-u){g}(u)\,dv\,du.$$
By Fubini's theorem,
\begin{align*}&\iint_{D_{{L}}}e^{-{s}v}{f}(v-u){g}(u)\,dv\,du=\int_0^{{L}}\int_0^ve^{-{s}v}{f}(v-u){g}(u)\,du\,dv\\
\\
&=\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}v}\int_0^v{f}(v-u){g}(u)\,du\,dv=\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}v}({f}\ast{g})(v)\,dv.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\iint_{D_{{L}}}e^{-{s}v}{f}(v-u){g}(u)\,dv\,du&=\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\int_0^{{L}}e^{-{s}v}({f}\ast{g})(v)\,dv\\
\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-{s}v}({f}\ast{g})(v)\,dv\\
\\
&=\mathcal{L}\{{f}\ast{g}\}({s}).
\end{align*}

Comment: I know its super late but could you tell me why $$\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\iint_{R_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du=\lim_{{{L}}\to\infty}\iint_{T_{{L}}}e^{-{s}(t+u)}{f}(t){g}(u)\,dt\,du$$@ashpool. How the integration over square region are same with triangle region?

Comment: The integrations over $R_L$ and $T_L$ may be different, but their limits are the same; see Lax & Terrel's Multivariable Calculus with Applications, section 6.5.